# error installing mysql-python and none of mentioned solutions worked

Tags: mysql-python

I just wanted to install Mysql-python, but every time errors occur.
I have tried all mentioned solutions as installing wheel, using easy_install, renewing visual c++ for python, installing mysql connector, even installing latest mysql itself,and every other things came to my sight and my mind.
 I have python 2.7.11 on windows 10. and I have installed most of windows updates.
always it occurs:

```
easy_install Mysql-python
Searching for Mysql-python
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/Mysql-python/
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.5
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Writing c:\users\aref\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-nhmvzf\MySQL-python-1.2.5\setup.cfg
Running MySQL-python-1.2.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\aref\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-nhmvzf\MySQL-python-1.2.5\egg-dist-tmp-idut0x
_mysql.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(203) : warning C4005: 'SIZEOF_OFF_T' : macro redefinition
        c:\python27\include\pyconfig.h(353) : see previous definition of 'SIZEOF_OFF_T'
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\config-win.h(301) : warning C4005: 'HAVE_STDDEF_H' : macro redefinition
        c:\python27\include\pyconfig.h(693) : see previous definition of 'HAVE_STDDEF_H'
_mysql.c(287) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(317) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(470) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(1168) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(1274) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(1466) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(1468) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(1504) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(1506) : warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
_mysql.c(1532) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
_mysql.c(2302) : warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
_mysql.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'init_mysql' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.exp
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_error referenced in function _mysql_Exception
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_errno referenced in function _mysql_Exception
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_server_init referenced in function _mysql_server_init
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_server_end referenced in function _mysql_server_end
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_thread_safe referenced in function _mysql_thread_safe
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_fields referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_fields referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_field_count referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_store_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_use_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_connect referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_ssl_set referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_options referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_init referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_close referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_close
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_affected_rows referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_affected_rows
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_debug referenced in function _mysql_debug
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_dump_debug_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_dump_debug_info
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_autocommit referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_autocommit
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_commit referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_commit
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_rollback referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_rollback
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_next_result referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_next_result
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_set_server_option referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_set_server_option
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_sqlstate referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_sqlstate
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_warning_count referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_warning_count
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_escape_string referenced in function _mysql_escape_string
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_escape_string referenced in function _mysql_escape_string
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_lengths referenced in function _mysql_row_to_tuple
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncat referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol memset referenced in function _mysql_row_to_dict_old
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_row referenced in function _mysql__fetch_row
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_num_rows referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_fetch_row
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_change_user referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_change_user
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_character_set_name referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_character_set_name
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_set_character_set referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_set_character_set
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_character_set_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_character_set_info
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_client_info referenced in function _mysql_get_client_info
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_host_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_host_info
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_proto_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_proto_info
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_get_server_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_get_server_info
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_info referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_info
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_insert_id referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_insert_id
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_kill referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_kill
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_ping referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_ping
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_query referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_query
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_select_db referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_select_db
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_shutdown referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_shutdown
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_stat referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_stat
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_thread_id referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_thread_id
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_sprintf referenced in function _mysql_ConnectionObject_repr
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_data_seek referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_data_seek
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_row_seek referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_row_seek
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_row_tell referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_row_seek
_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_free_result referenced in function _mysql_ResultObject_dealloc
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup
build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_mysql.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 56 unresolved externals
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Users\\aref\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: I finally migrated from python 2.7.11  to 2.7.12 and my never solved problems are solved also this dump error..

Comment: Just to add, I personally kept getting errors when trying other solutions found on git and stack. 

But once I installed the mysqlclient and then tried "import MySQLdb" in the code it worked despite the errors in the terminal 

stackoverflow.com/a/42067480/3680309 +1 for me

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. That's what I did to solve it:

1. Download mysqlclient whl file from
   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient (eg. if you
   have Python 3.6 on Win64, download
   mysqlclient‑1.3.9‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl).
2. `pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.9‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`
3. `import MySQLdb` should now work in Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem as you none of the other answers seem to work for me,

e.g - [Compiling mysql-python on Windows with PIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552593/compiling-mysql-python-on-windows-with-pip)

This a variation on a different answer that worked

1. pip install mysqlclient
2. "import MySQLdb" should now work within the code

alternatively, you can add this code

```
try:

    import MySQLdb as mysql

except Exception as e:

    import os 
    os.system("pip install mysqlclient")
    import MySQLdb as mysql

db = mysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db);
```